# Multitenancy using data segregation in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I'm working on a new application, that will be used by dozens of clients, each client also with dozens of users. I really don't want to handle with multiple datasources (because that may lead to performance issues), so I choose to use only 1 database for all tenants, and prepare the application to handle multitenancy through logical data segregation (creating a tenant id with my entities and indexing all tables with this ID).

But, I was wondering, in case of a client need to restore it's backup, in order to prevent the down time of the entire system, is it possible (or viable) to address this problem creating all tables partitioned by tenant id? In this case, can I performe a backup/restore by partition on Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, backup and restore of table partitions is possible. See here in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmresind.htm#BRADV696.

Also see here for examples:

- https://www.thegeekdiary.com/oracle-database-12c-new-feature-rman-recover-table/
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/rman-table-point-in-time-recovery-12cr1